# How to install certutil on Centos?

Tags: centos-8, certutil

I am trying to get libreswan VPN running on my centos system but I seem to be missing the certutil package

```
/usr/local/sbin/ipsec: line 394: certutil: command not found
```

However I have been looking everywhere and I cannot find certutil. Any suggestions which package contains it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, you can search for which package provides `certutil`:

```
yum provides */certutil
```

Then just install with:

```
yum install <packagename>
```

Apparently it's provided by the package `nss-tools` and all of this is easily searchable in Google.

Comment: Such an easy fix, don't know how I didn't think of this earlier. Thanks for the help!